# Rails validate model with attribute using uniqness

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

Assume that i have a person that have a certificate, which a certificate (uniq) have an publish date and expired date. What i'm going to ask is how can i make a validation so a same person can have a same certificate with condition that publish date of new certificate (in this case still a same certificate) should be more than expired date of old certificate.
Thank's for advanced.

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what you are asking for.

Comment: Well, the problem is. i trying creating a new record with same person and same certificate, but i have a validation "validates :certificate_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :person_id}". So this is make impossible for creating a new record with same person and same certificate. What i want is, a can create a same person with same certificate but the new publish date of certificate should be greater than expire date of the old one. Sorry for bad explanation

Comment: how about making 1 person : n certificates? Basically when Certificate C1 of person A is expired he can get another certificate C2. Hope that helps

Comment: I want renew a C1 not getting a new of certificate, but thanks for advanced